# OrmLite (ServiceStack): Only use temporary db-connections (use 'using'?)

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, datareader

For the last 10+ years or so, I have always opened a connection the database (mysql) and kept it open, until the application closed. All queries was executed on the connection.

Now, when I see examples on Servicestack webpage, i always see the `using`-block being used, like:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    if (db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Poco>())
    {
        db.Insert(new Poco { Id = 1, Name = "Seed Data"});
    }

    var result = db.SingleById<Poco>(1);
    result.PrintDump(); //= {Id: 1, Name:Seed Data}
}
```

In my current test-project, I got OrmLite to work in my normal way (one db-connection, no using-statements), so I basically had a class-wide `_db`, like this:

```
_dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory($"Uid={dbAccount.Username};Password={dbAccount.Password};Server={dbAccount.Address};Port={dbAccount.Port};Database={dbAccount.Database}", MySqlDialect.Provider);

_db = _dbFactory.Open(); // var kept in memory, and used for all queries
```

It worked in the beginning, but now I suddenly got the Exception:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Some code might run a SELECT here and there, and if I understand it correctly, if a SELECT and an INSERT would occur at the same time, this error appears?

If so, is it best-practice to always open a *new* connection for every single query (say, inside a using-statement)? Isnt that a big overhead, to do what for every query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having 1 DB Connection is not ThreadSafe so holding on to the connection is only an option if there’s at most 1 thread accessing the DB connection.

Most ADO.NET providers enable connection pooling by default so it’s more efficient to close the connection when you’re done with it as the connection gets returned back to the pool which reduces the number of active connections in use.

Comment: Thx for always answering very fast, appreciated! Right, so the using-way is the way to go then. .Open() doesnt affect performance then, per default?

Comment: Not if the ADO.NET provider has pooling enabled (it can be disabled in the connection string), calling .Open() just retrieves an open connection from the pool.